# C++ File Input 3 ints on line reading

Tags: c++, fileinputstream

so I have a file for C++ that I am reading in. It has 3 ints `4 4 16` looks like that. I'm curious as to how I go about getting this all read into 3 variables that I have `cars carCapacity people`

I have set up two different ways of trying to get them but neither are working. I just get an infinite loop

`fin >> cars >> carCapacity >> people;` Is one way that I'm trying to store the input. another was:

`fin >> cars;`

`fin >> carCapacity`

`fin >> people`

I'm using an `ifstream` to get the file, I check to make sure that there is a file and then I use `while(!fin.eof())` to loop the entire txt file. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: See [while feof file is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use "freeopen"

```
file: a.txt
1 2 3

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
   freeopen("a.txt", "r", stdin);
   int a, b, c;
   std::cin >> a >> b >> c;
   std::cout << a << b << c;
}
```

P/s: I don't test

Comment: Thanks! This is working for me. Now I just need to get out of the file loop

Comment: How do you justify not using the standard `<fstream>` ? What is freeopen ? Is it freopen ? How is reopening a stream relevant here ?

Comment: When you use freeopen the input / output stream will be streaming a file, replacing the console stream. But this is for those using small files, even large files, I still suggest using ifstream in C + + or can be used in C FILE pointer to get the best rate. 
p / s: I'm a Vietnam so bad english: (

Comment: if you want to write file can use: freeopen("b.txt", "w", stdout);